# NSArray - storing and retrieving data for a table using a button

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsuserdefaults, nsdata

I am trying to store data into NSArray using a button and then retrieve it to be displayed in a table. However, the table remains empty after the button has been pushed. I think the problem might have to do with how the Car object is being added to the array and then stored in NSData.

CarTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CarDetailViewController.h"
#import "Car.h"

@interface CarListTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property Car *selectedCar;
@property NSMutableArray *listOfCars;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *carTableView;
@end
```

CarTableViewController.m

```
#import "CarListTableViewController.h"
#import "CarEntryViewController.h"

@implementation CarListTableViewController
@synthesize selectedCar, listOfCars, carTableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    carTableView.delegate = self;
    carTableView.dataSource = self;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return listOfCars.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"carCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"carCell"];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    }
    Car *tempCar =[listOfCars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text =tempCar.make;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:true];
    selectedCar = [listOfCars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewDetailsSegue" sender:nil];
}

#pragma mark - Navigation

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    CarDetailViewController* vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc.carObject = selectedCar;
}

- (NSArray*) retrieveDataFromNSUserDefaults {
    NSMutableArray *objectArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *dataRepresentingSavedArray = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"savedArray"];
    if (dataRepresentingSavedArray != nil) {
        NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingSavedArray];
        if (oldSavedArray != nil)
            objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]
                           initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
        else
            objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return objectArray;
}

- (void)storeDataInNSUserDefaults:(Car *)carToStore {
    NSMutableArray *objectArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self retrieveDataFromNSUserDefaults]];
    [objectArray addObject:carToStore];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:objectArray] forKey:@"savedArray"];
}

@end
```

Comment: FYI - `NSUserDefaults` is not the place to store data.

Answer (score 2):

your code looks fine to me but I think you are not calling method to add data `[self storeDataInNSUserDefaults:car]` anywhere.